# Angular: Recursive calling of ngFor's

Tags: angular

I have a JSON that has some nested objects in it. So to show them in view, I created this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of trees">
    <div *ngFor="let obj of item | keyvalue">
        <div *ngFor="let obj1 of obj.value | keyvalue">
            <div *ngIf="!ifLeaf(obj1.value)">
                <b>{{ obj1.key }}</b>
                <div *ngFor="let obj2 of obj1.value | keyvalue">
                    <div *ngIf="ifLeaf(obj2.value)">
                        <i>{{ obj2.key }}</i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JSON looks like that:

```
trees[
        header: {
            first: {
                title: {
                    name: "Test"
                }
            },
            second: {
                title: {
                    top: {
                        name: "Test"
                    }
                },
                desc: {
                    name: "Test"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

That code can show up to 2 nested objects with its keys and values. But what if the last object has 3 more nested objects within its own object? Is there a way that I can do that dynamically, without hardcoding? I'm sure there are better solutions for that. I'd be really thankful!

Comment: Try using some treeview package to which you pass nested object!

Comment: Can you show `trees`

Comment: maybe you should **spread** the object in TS file and use that in HTML. You can write a recursive function to spread the object. Since deepness of nested object is unknown only option could be a recursive function

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by creating a recursive component. For example https://netbasal.com/recursion-in-angular-components-1cd636269b12